# How to design a global class for storing settings in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, class, typescript

I have added a class like this.

```
export class Settings{
  public data: string = "blopp";
}
```

When I try to access the data, it seems that the field I'm trying to assign that value to sees the class *Settings* itself **but** it doesn't recognize the *data* thingy.

How do I redesign the class to provide settings for other components?

I've read about *@Output* decorator but since I won't be binding to the values, it seems not the correct approach. I've made sure that the class is imported and recognized withing the component that's supposed to consume it. I've also tried the corresponding exposure but using a function in the class with settings - the same, failed result.

Comment: Read this [**medium**](https://medium.com/@hasan.hameed/reading-configuration-files-in-angular-2-9d18b7a6aa4) post for more information.

Comment: Just use built in `environment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using angular-cli and going to store in this class environment specific settings - you already have built in support for this.

Put the setting into `environment.ts`. For example:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    someSetting: 'foo',
};
```

Then it can be consumed from anywhere within the app:

```
import { environment } from "../environments/environment"; //fix according to your project structure

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
    private foo = environment.someSetting;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments) you can find more info on how to add more environments and build you project with specific environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for storing global settings is to use a service. The code for that looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

I have a blog post about this here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

And a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

Also, the `@Output` decorator is only for communication between a child component and a parent component where the child is nested within the parent.

Comment: I see - that's a new one to me (Angular is general is). While I was waiting for the answer, I discovered that we have the keyword *static* in TS, so I used that instead, which gave me a statically accessible field that supports the syntax in my question. I wonder what's your take on that (as compared to the injectable service that you've suggested).

Comment: An injectable service is not actially required here. A class with static variables will be a good option.

Comment: @Faisal That's what I figure too. However, undeniably, as I've googled he issue, it seems to be a bit of industry standard to create an injectable service and use that. Somewhere I've read a comment that such an approach is not the best for **every** situation but that it's an artifact from the era of dominance of AngularJs and that the developers simply haven't adapted the new alternative offered by *static*. What do you think?

Comment: @AndyJ A class with static props only makes no sense and usually indicates wrong understanding of OOP concepts. Use a plain object if you need to instantiate a class 0 to 1 times. As the answer shows, in Angular such cases are usually handled by providers. The class is a singleton, yet it gets the benefits of DI (extensibility and testability).